# Integral of ydx + xdy

Tags: integration, differential

I know this is a very simple question but why is this wrong?$$\int(xdy+ydx)=\int xdy+\int ydx=x\int dy+y\int dx=2xy$$

I saw a similar question on Stack Exchange, but it was too complicated for me to understand. I am in 11th Grade and I have just done basic differentiation and integration for physics. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you link to the similar question you saw elsewhere?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300023/easy-question-int-xdyydx here

Comment: generally everything is wrong if you integrate without limits. In first place you need to define the integral properly making it a definite integral, after you will need to parameterize the functions $x$ and $y$ to finally get an answer. take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623795/given-vecf-y-x-calculate-contour-integral-int-c-vecf-vecdr-on-l)

Comment: @Masacroso “everything is wrong if you integrate without limits” — Seriously? That goes against the entire concept of an indefinite integral.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish an indefinite integral is, in general, not well defined, by example $\int x^{-1/2} \mathop{}\!d x=\ln|x|+C$ doesn't make sense if you consider, by example $\int_{-1}^1 x^{-1}\mathop{}\!d x$. There are plenty of examples with different behavior showing how bad behaved is the concept of indefinite integral.

Comment: @Masacroso Everyone knows that particular indefinite integral, like some others, has a restriction on the domain of integration. That doesn’t mean “everything is wrong.”

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish when something is not well-defined then "everything is wrong" is to me a fine and correct way to describe it.

Comment: @Masacroso My point is that you were saying one must define limits of integration before continuing with this problem, and as J.G. demonstrated, that’s simply not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x,\,y$ are in general not independent, you can't treat $x$ as a constant as in $\int xdy=x\int dy$. Your original problem would make this clearer if you wrote $x(y)dy+y(x)dx$. In fact,$$\int(xdy+ydx)=\int d(xy)=xy+C.$$

Comment: But if we move parallel to the x-axis first and then parallel to the y-axis, won't we get 2xy.

Comment: @Niescte No, because you'll move at an angle. Let's consider the example $y=x$. As you try to vary $x$, you'll vary $y$ instead & vice versa. In this case, the problem reduces to $\int2xdx=x^2+C=xy+C$.

Comment: Ok, i get it now. If we move parallel to the x axis first, then the value of x should change the next time when we integrate it moving parallel to y.